# How can I resolve a registered Dependency from an Autofac Container in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

There's a project I'm trying to upgrade to .NET Core 3.1 from 2.2. My major issue is at the startup.cs where I'm registering dependencies with Autofac. I have studied the documentation for registering dependencies in 3.0 and I understand it. But there is a requirement in `ConfigureServices` method to register an object as an instance and it requires the container to resolve a registered service in the same method as seen in the code below

**Startup.cs (2.2)**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IExecutionContextAccessor, ExecutionContextAccessor>();

    //other services registered

    return CreateAutofacServiceProvider(services);
}

private IServiceProvider CreateAutofacServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

    containerBuilder.Populate(services);

    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new MyModule());

    var container = containerBuilder.Build();

    var httpContextAccessor = container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var executionContextAccessor = new ExecutionContextAccessor(httpContextAccessor);

    var emailsConfiguration = new EmailsConfiguration(_configuration["EmailsConfiguration:FromEmail"]);

    // executionContextAccessor is used to initialize some modules here

    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

In .net core 3.1, I couldn't find a clear means of replicating the above with the new Autofac approach.

**Startup (3.1)**

```
public ILifetimeScope AutofacContainer { get; private set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IExecutionContextAccessor, ExecutionContextAccessor>();

    // other services registered

    var httpContextAccessor = this.AutofacContainer.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var executionContextAccessor = new ExecutionContextAccessor(httpContextAccessor);

    var emailsConfiguration = new EmailsConfiguration(_configuration["EmailsConfiguration:FromEmail"]);

    // executionContextAccessor is used to initialize some modules here
}

public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new MyModule());
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    this.AutofacContainer = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();

    // other stuff
}
```

`this.AutofacContainer` throws null reference at runtime. I am not surprised by this because `ConfigureServices` executes before `Configure` method where I get references to the registered dependencies in the container. I can't seem to find a way to resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` from the container in `ConfigureServices` and use it as it is in netcore 2.2.

For clarity, Please see how the `executionContextAccessor` is used in the class that does the initialization as done in netcoreapp2.2:

```
public class ModuleStartup
{
    private static IContainer _container;

    public static void Initialize(
        IExecutionContextAccessor executionContextAccessor,
        EmailsConfiguration emailsConfiguration)
    {
        ConfigureCompositionRoot(
            executionContextAccessor,
            emailsConfiguration);
    }

    private static void ConfigureCompositionRoot(
        IExecutionContextAccessor executionContextAccessor,
        EmailsConfiguration emailsConfiguration)
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new EmailModule(emailsConfiguration)); 

        containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(executionContextAccessor);

        _container = containerBuilder.Build();

        ModuleCompositionRoot.SetContainer(_container);
    }

    Internal static class ModuleCompositionRoot
    {
        private static IContainer _container;

        internal static void SetContainer(IContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        internal static ILifetimeScope BeginLifetimeScope()
        {
            return _container.BeginLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how the modules that use `executionContextAccessor` are initialized. You can use the factory delegate when registering them so you have access to the service provider. You are not showing the important details needed to answer this question.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for your response. Actually the solution is big which is why I tried to post the relevant codes. But see my edited question to see the part that uses the `executionContextAccessor`. Actually it registers it as an instance. I tried to trim the code to small block as it contains a lot of other stuff that doesn't relate to the question. Kindly explain how I use the factory delegate. Thanks

Comment: Did you find you the answer to your problem? I am kind of stuck in a similar situation. My biggest question is how to access the Autofac container reference once apply ContainerBuilder.build()

Comment: @Toxic my solution was to ditch the generic host model and used the webhost which is possible in netcore3.1. By so doing my stratup class remained unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in `Configure` although I wouldn't recommend it as you're splitting the responsibility of registering your dependencies across multiple parts of your startup. This will resolve the IHttpContextAccessor through `IApplicationBuilder.GetServce<TService>()` which you can then use for subsequent registrations.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var executionContextAccessor = new ExecutionContextAccessor(httpContextAccessor);
            var emailsConfiguration = new EmailsConfiguration(_configuration["EmailsConfiguration:FromEmail"]);

            ModuleStartup.Initialize(executionContextAccessor, emailsConfiguration);
        }
```

Likewise, you could also resolve the IExecutionContextAccessor in order to add registrations like so.

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var executionContextAccessor = new ExecutionContextAccessor(httpContextAccessor);

            var fooToRegister = new Foo(executionContextAccessor);

            var registration = RegistrationBuilder
                .ForDelegate<IAnotherInterface>((c, p) => fooToRegister)
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                .CreateRegistration();

            app.ApplicationServices
                .GetAutofacRoot().ComponentRegistry
                .Register(registration);
        }
```